# Can get call work as post call to create node or login as a user in drupal 6 from external source like mobile app

Tags: 6, services, theming

I have setup a Rest server in my Drupal 6 site. I am able to successfully post new node and login as a user using `method:POST` from Rest client in Firefox. I want to do the same things using a get call.

I tried doing the following to login using GET method:

```
http://test.dabeastv2.gotpantheon.com/disk/user/login?username=sddfsg&password=sdf
```

It tells me that "**there is no user with ID login**"

Can someone please help me?.

Comment: Drupal's login form uses `method="post"` - what have you done Drupal-side to make it accept GET logins?

Comment: I though Services module might be able to handle it. Can you please explain what should be done on drupal side to make it accept GET logins as well as node create forms to accept GET  to create node

Comment: Sorry, missed the fact you are using services module. Anyway, accepting GET logins is a security risk - GET URL can be bookmarked, indexed by search engines and so on. Once upon a time I got admin rights in internet bookstore just by clicking a link in Google! Without even trying! So I guess it might be explicitly disabled. Huh, I think it *should* be disabled until admin enables it and accepts a big red security warning. On the other hand accidental node creation by one who is allowed to create nodes is no risk at all, just easily corrected mistake.

Comment: I just need this to enable node creation by authenticated users from our mobile app. Its important as POST requests are getting converted into OPTIONS and hence always producing errors. Please tell me a way to do this over GET request. The user will need to be authenticated to create node. So I think its moderately secure. Moreover, I can handle security at a later stage.

Comment: @Mołot How to enable it as admin ? I might sound dumb but please tell me.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that familiar with services, and I will not be able to play with it sooner than in about 14 hours. Even them I can't promise I'll find it.